# I need jQuery to perform a task if two conditions are true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help to put an if statement together using jQuery. I want to change the logo on my site, if two conditions are true.

Here is some pseudo code, hopefully explaining what i want to archive:

```
if(li hasClass active and data-menuid is equal to 0033){
    change logo...
}
```

Here is a simple example of the menu structure:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menu-primary">
        <li class="menuactive" data-menuid="0011">
        Test1
            <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                <li data-menuid="0022">Test2</li>
                <li class="active" data-menuid="0033">Test3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-menuid="0044">Test4</li>
        <li data-menuid="0055">Test5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Under what event are you trying to check the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the combination of class and [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
if($('li.menuactive[data-menuid="0033"]').length){
    //Your code to change the logo
}
```

---

You can use [`$.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var listMeetingCondition = $('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('menuactive') && $(this).attr('data-menuid') == "0033"
});

if(listMeetingCondition.length){
    //Your code to change the logo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('li:has(.menuactive[data-menuid="0033"])').length){
    change logo...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I tried to add an else statement, but non of them is executing.

Comment: @thar, can you replicate it in a fiddle?

Comment: @thar, you need to make sure jquery is included. See it working here https://jsfiddle.net/psyntr0d/1/

Comment: @AnnarCSE, jQuery are included, but working with Wordpress, is need to use jQuery() and not $(). Thanks for your time, its working... :)

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

```
var $target = $('li', '#menu-primary');
if( $target.hasclass('active') && $target.data('menuid') == '0033' ){
    // change logo
}
```